# What is the word for the verb that signifies performing the action suggested by a given noun?

Tags: single-word-requests, verbs, esl

I realize the wording is a little difficult to parse; essentially, I'm asking how to fill in the following blanks:

The ___ of "mistake" is "make".

The ___ of "action" is "perform".

The ___ of "party" is "throw".

The ___ of "campaign" is ___.

Compound words are, of course, perfectly acceptable. A similar question suggested "performative verb", but [the Wikipedia description](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Performative_verb) seems to be referencing something else.

Comment: I am not aware of any term appropriate for such a general a set of examples. They are simply verbs, with the other word in each example being a noun serving as a direct object. Also note that *to throw a party* may be considered an idiomatic expression, because the context forces a specific understanding of certain words.

Comment: Also *performant verb* appears to be unrelated, as referring to a statement that carries legal or procedural force. One cannot claim to hold a particular job the day after saying "I quit", because the act of quitting occurs simply because of saying so.

Comment: I see. Regardless, do you know what would be the verb corresponding to "campaign"? If helpful, the context is "(...) injection campaigns, such as the ones ___ to treat sleeping sickness". Could "coordinated" fill in this blank?

Comment: In the context you have provided, I would not say that any single word is appropriate. The particular phrase "injection campaign" has no specific meaning. One might write, "conducting a campaign against sleeping sickness by providing injections" to describe the ongoing activity, or "launch a campaign against sleeping sickness that will provide injections" to describe the beginning.

Comment: Well, there's always "verbing a noun".

Comment: Actually, I'd suggest "action".  Or maybe some obscure synonym.

Comment: I think OP is asking about the *licensing* of verbs.  Party licenses throw. Action licenses perform.  One of the verbs licensed by mistake is make.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I am unaware of any specific word for this, I would call the blank in each example sentence (or the first blank in the last example sentence) a *verbal antecedent*.

This is a mix of the two normal senses of the word [**antecedent**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/antecedent) (along with the definition of *verbal* in its sense of grammar rather than speech):

> [Merriam-Webster]
>
> **1** *grammar* : a substantive word, phrase, or clause whose denotation is referred to by a pronoun (such as *John* in "Mary saw John and called to him")
>
> *broadly* : a word or phrase replaced by a substitute
>
> **2 a** : a preceding event, condition, or cause
> // events that were *antecedents* of the war
>
> **2 b** **antecedents** *plural* : the significant events, conditions, and traits of one's earlier life

Neither sense directly matches, but the combination of the two does.

In other words, the examples could be rephrased::

> The *verbal antecedent* of "mistake" is "make."
> → *She [made] something. She [made] a mistake.*
>
> The *verbal antecedent* of "action" is "perform."
> → *He [performed] something. He [performed] an action.*
>
> The *verbal antecedent* of "campaign" is "**planned**."
> → *They [**planned**] something. They [**planned**] a campaign.*

---

In the first example, for instance, *make* is the verb that antecedes the noun *mistake*.

And in the last example, other verbs could also be used, such as *conducted* or *launched*, as suggested in a comment under the question, or *executed*.

Which verbs commonly go with which nouns could be called [*collocations*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/collocation).